# Почему вк не даёт почту при запросе с сервера по токену полученному при авторизации на айфоне?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

У нас было приложение на андроиде, там была авторизация через вк сдк. Пользователь давал разрешение на использование почты (запускалось приложение вк, где пользователь подтверждал разрешение), а потом сдк возвращал вк токен доступа. Этот токен приложение отправляло на наш сервер, с которого делался запрос по этому токену к вк.

```php
function curl( $url ) {
        $ch = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        $response = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        return json_decode($response , true);
    }

    $params = array(
        'user_id'         => $_POST['user_id'],
        'fields'       => 'uid,first_name,last_name,screen_name,sex,bdate,photo_big',
        'access_token' => $_POST['access_token']
    );

    $userInfo = curl('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params)));
```

И вк возвращал почту пользователя.

Но теперь мы реализуем то же самое в приложении под ios. Правда не родная вк сдк, а через swiftyVK. Пользователь авторизуется через приложение вк, установленное на его устройстве. Наше приложение получает токен вк, этот токен отправляется на наш сервер и оттуда тем же способом делается запрос на сервер вк. Но в этом случае вк возвращает такой ответ:

```JSON
{"error":{"error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: access_token was given to another ip address.","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"users.get"},{"key":"user_id","value":"400973675"},{"key":"fields","value":"uid,first_name,last_name,screen_name,sex,bdate,photo_big"}]}}
```

Почему такой результат для айфона, если на андроиде полученный токен даёт доступ к данным пользователя и не пишет что ip другой?

Comment: А что используется на андроиде? Родной SDK или кто-то другой? Запрос абсолютно такой же?

Comment: Да, используется родной сдк от вк. И точно такой же scope.

Comment: flow в обоих случаях одинаковый?

Comment: Возможно, это баг в СДК на андроиде?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman что значит flow?

Comment: @VladD не знаю, мне кажется нет

Comment: @cheerful_weasel есть несколько вариантов авторизации. Они описаны на сайте ВК и носят названия Implicit flow, Authorization Code Flow, Client Credentials Flow. Вот эти flow.

Comment: Вы в vkWillAuthorize передаете необходимые scope? (.email)?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman честно говоря я не знаю какой flow используется. Я запускаю авторизацию при помощи VKSdk.login в андроиде, а в ios VK.autorize().

Comment: @VAndrJ да scope одинаковый и там и там email.